# Why is the last iteration of this code is not working properly?

Tags: c, loops, iteration

I am writing a program that prints the first 50 Fibonacci numbers, starting with 1 and 2.
The numbers must be separated by a comma, followed by a space except the last number, it should end with a new line instead.

the code I tried:

```
int main(void)
{
    int fib[50];
    fib[0] = 1;
    fib[1] = 2;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            printf("%d ,", fib[0]);
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            printf("%d ,", fib[1]);
        }
        else if (i == 49)
        {
            fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
            printf("%d", fib[i]);
        }
        else 
        {
            fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
            printf("%d ,", fib[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return (0);
}
```

the result I get:

```
1 ,2 ,3 ,5 ,8 ,13 ,21 ,34 ,55 ,89 ,144 ,233 ,377 ,610 ,987 ,1597 ,2584 ,4181 ,6765 ,10946 ,17711 ,28657 ,46368 ,75025 ,121393 ,196418 ,317811 ,514229 ,832040 ,1346269 ,2178309 ,3524578 ,5702887 ,9227465 ,14930352 ,24157817 ,39088169 ,63245986 ,102334155 ,165580141 ,267914296 ,433494437 ,701408733 ,1134903170 ,1836311903 ,2971215073 ,512559680 ,3483774753 ,3996334433 ,3185141890 ,
```

Comment: An `int` is typically 32 bits. Since it's signed, it can hold values between around minus two billion to plus two billion. The 47:th Fibonacci number will be larger than that, leading to a signed integer arithmetic overflow which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As a workaround you can use a larger type, like `uint64_t` (which is not only much larger, but also unsigned so will not have UB when it overflows). It will give you some margin for going even higher, but it's still not limitless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you must include `<stdio.h>` to use `printf` correctly. You might have forgotten the `#include` line in the question code, but as posted, the code has undefined behavior.
- on the vast majority of current systems, the type `int` is not large enough to accommodate the values of Fibonacci numbers up to 49. You should use type `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` that are guaranteed to handle numbers up to **2<sup>63</sup>-1** (resp. **2<sup>64</sup>-1**).
- the format string `"%d ,"` is incorrect: the space should appear **after** the comma, not before.
- the output posted is inconsistent with the code: some of the numbers are larger than **2<sup>31</sup>-1**. Here is the output I get with your code:

  ```
  1 ,2 ,3 ,5 ,8 ,13 ,21 ,34 ,55 ,89 ,144 ,233 ,377 ,610 ,987 ,1597 ,2584 ,4181 ,6765 ,10946 ,17711 ,28657 ,46368 ,75025 ,121393 ,196418 ,317811 ,514229 ,832040 ,1346269 ,2178309 ,3524578 ,5702887 ,9227465 ,14930352 ,24157817 ,39088169 ,63245986 ,102334155 ,165580141 ,267914296 ,433494437 ,701408733 ,1134903170 ,1836311903 ,-1323752223 ,512559680 ,-811192543 ,-298632863 ,-1109825406
  ```

  Note however that the behavior on signed integer overflow is undefined so other behaviors are possible albeit unlikely.
- there is no need for an array, you can just use 3 variables and cycle them.
- it is easier to make a special case of the first 2 numbers and output the `,` and a space before each of the next numbers.
- whether you want to print the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence) starting with `1, 2` or `0, 1` or even `1, 1` is a question of convention. The Italian mathematician [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci) himself used `1, 2` in his time (1202 AD) as he was discussing rabbit population growth in his [*Liber Abaci*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Liber_abbaci_magliab_f124r.jpg).  As a matter of fact, Fibonacci is credited for introducing the base 10 notation in Europe and the concept of [zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0), imported from the Arab world where he grew up. The numbers in the picture of the manuscript show the sequence numbers using a variant of [Indo-Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system). In modern times, it is more conventional to start the sequence at `0, 1` and to name these as *F<sub>0</sub>* and *F<sub>1</sub>*.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long a = 1, b = 2;

    printf("%llu, %llu", a, b);

    for (int i = 2; i < 50; ++i) {
        unsigned long long c = a + b;
        printf(", %llu", c);
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only assume you are experiencing `int` overflow. There is a finite (platform specific) range to an `int` value. Try a `long long`. Also, you could simplify the logic here quite a bit. For example, you could print the first two values before the loop; after that the logic is regular and requires no `if`(s). Like,

```
int i;
long long fib[50];
fib[0] = 1;
fib[1] = 2;

printf("%lld, %lld", fib[0], fib[1]);
for (i = 2; i < 50; i++)
{
    fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
    printf(", %lld", fib[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation, I understand my code is a bit nasty and not efficient, I am still a beginner. I tried your code and obviously it is great but I just wanted to know why didn't mine work? what did I do wrong?

Comment: @BeminDawoud *There is a finite (platform specific) range to an `int` value.* You exceeded the valid range. An `int` is (presumably on your platform) 32-bits. When you add two large 32-bit values together and the result exceeds 32-bits the value overflows (and turns negative). This is because binary values are stored in a two's complement representation. `-1` is all bits true.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the note on integer overflow, you can handle the commas in a concise manner by using a separator and changing it after your first iteration, rather than testing to see if you're on the last iteration.

There's also really no need to store an array of Fibonacci numbers if you're just outputting them. Instead we can just keep track of two numbers, and update them on each iteration.  `(0, 1) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (2, 3) -> ...` If we follow this algorithm, the first number on each iteration is the next Fibonacci number: `0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> ...`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint64_t a = 0, b = 1;
    const char *sep = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        printf("%s%lu", sep, a);
        sep = ", ";
        uint64_t c = a;
        a = b;
        b += c;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Which outputs:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049
```

Comment: thank you so much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

'long long' occupy more bytes to store the value, could avoid overflow in such situation.